# Smarter Boostrap Affix

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The normal boostrap affix doesn't take the items natural offset top position into account, you have to manually pass it in as an attribute. This takes care of that, and accounts for the offset top changing on window resize.

```
var $attribute = $('[data-smart-affix]');
$attribute.each(function(){
  $(this).affix({
    offset: {
      top: $(this).offset().top,
    }
  })
})
$(window).on("resize", function(){
  $attribute.each(function(){
    $(this).data('bs.affix').options.offset = $(this).offset().top
  })
})
```